# How to open specific windows to specific buttons on wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I did my research before coming here and couldn't find anything helpful. Please bare with me as I'm a newbie in wxWidgets and C++ GUI. I created a 3x3 grid, each button with its own purpose. When clicked, some should open a new page containing at least what the button text says, and other buttons should direct you to the website that's on the button. I tried creating a new window within the event handlers but nothing shows up even if I use `Show();`
I have a cApp, class which is the launcher for the application and cMain that is the graphical interface implementation. I will show cMain only.

**cMAIN.H**

```
#pragma once
//Graphical interface component
#include "wx/wx.h"

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();
public:
    int nFieldWidth = 3;
    int nFieldHeight = 3;
    wxButton** btn;
    
    void OnButtonClicked0(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void OnButtonClicked1(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked2(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked3(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked4(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked5(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked6(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked7(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    void OnButtonClicked8(wxCommandEvent &evt);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

**cMAIN.CPP**

```
#include "cMain.h"
#include "cApp.h"
#include <string>
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(cMain, wxFrame)
EVT_BUTTON(0, OnButtonClicked0)
EVT_BUTTON(1, OnButtonClicked1)
EVT_BUTTON(2, OnButtonClicked2)
EVT_BUTTON(3, OnButtonClicked3)
EVT_BUTTON(4, OnButtonClicked4)
EVT_BUTTON(5, OnButtonClicked5)
EVT_BUTTON(6, OnButtonClicked6)
EVT_BUTTON(7, OnButtonClicked7)
EVT_BUTTON(8, OnButtonClicked8)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE();


cMain::cMain() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "3x3Grid", wxPoint(30,30), wxSize(800,600))//overriding the frame
{
    btn = new wxButton * [nFieldWidth * nFieldHeight]; // creating an array of buttons of size nFW * nFH
    wxGridSizer* grid = new wxGridSizer(nFieldWidth, nFieldHeight, 10, 10); //creating new sizer grid

    wxFont font(24, wxFONTFAMILY_MODERN, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_BOLD, false);

    for (int x = 0; x < nFieldWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < nFieldHeight; y++)
        {
            btn[y * nFieldWidth + x] = new wxButton(this, 10000 + (y * nFieldWidth + x), std::to_string(y * nFieldWidth + x)); //sets button[index] = a new button
            btn[y * nFieldWidth + x]->SetFont(font); //set font
            grid->Add(btn[y * nFieldWidth + x], 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL); //adds button to grid
        }
    }
    btn[0]->SetLabel("Input Data");
    btn[1]->SetLabel("Read Data from File");
    btn[2]->SetLabel("Open www.website.com");
    btn[3]->SetLabel("Lookup Data");
    btn[4]->SetLabel("Open website.com");
    btn[5]->SetLabel("Open https://website.com");
    btn[6]->SetLabel("Store Data to File");
    btn[7]->SetLabel("Open https://website.com");
    btn[8]->SetLabel("Help");

    this->SetSizer(grid);
    grid->Layout();
    
}


cMain::~cMain()
{
    delete[]btn;
}

void cMain::OnButtonClicked0(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
    cMain* inputwindow = new cMain();
    inputwindow->Show();
}

void cMain::OnButtonClicked1(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked2(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked3(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked4(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked5(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked6(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked7(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
void cMain::OnButtonClicked8(wxCommandEvent& evt)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button ID and the EVT_BUTTON(id) don't match. e.g. Button 0's id is 10000, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the previous reply:

You should consider using `wxID_HIGHEST` instead of 1000 or just use wxID_ANY along with `Bind()` function.